# Migrating SAP Sybase ASE to AZURE

Tags: azure, database-migration, sap-ase

Im new to the cloud universe of Microsoft and confused with their Migration Services, so forgive me if this question seems like there was no effort put into finding an answer myself.

Im evaluating to migratre our Sybase ASE 16 environment to the Cloud, preferably to AZURE, because of Sybase and Microsoft both rely on T-SQL for procedural programming. This being said I was looking through the docs and could not find any out of the box cloud migrating solution for Sybase.

Link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/dms/resource-scenario-status

I understand Microsofts definitions of offline and online migration but neither offer a service for Sybase products. I then stumbled up on SSMA ( Micrsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for SAP Sybase ASE). From my understanding this is a tool to migrate a Sybase Database to a Microsoft SQL Server Database and has nothing to with AZURE.

But I could have an AZURE DB sitting in the cloud and just use it as the destination for my migration?

Is this best practice for SAP Sybase ASE migrations to AZURE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure offers a migration tool to migrate to the cloud. If you need to migrate a Sybase Database you will need to use Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for SAP.

In order to migrate your Sybase Database you need to download the SSMA Client and the extension pack for your Microsoft SQL Server.

Inside the SSMA you first have to convert selected database schemas, then synchronize them in the bottom database explorer with your destination database and then you are ready to hit the migration button.

Keep in mind that Microsoft SQL Server is case insensitive by default but you can change the case sensivity on a database level for sysdb in Microsoft SQL Server Manager.

Also it is important to point out that this tool only migrates DDL but not users and permissions.